# How to retrieve a mysqli variable in a function

Tags: php, mysqli

In a function I want to use an if statement to look up a mysqli `bind_result()` variable `if($qandaReplyType == 'Single'){`but I am getting an undefined variable when attempting this. I looked at some SO examples but I do not understand to implement it correctly. So my question is that can somebody provide a code snippet in order to be able to fix the error and also for me to see how a mysqli variable should be retrieved in a function for future use and to give me full understanding on how it should be written.

CODE:

```
$qandaquery = "SELECT q.QuestionId ReplyType
                            FROM QuestionId q
                            INNER JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId

        ...

            $qandaqrystmt->bind_result($qandaQuestionId,$qandaReplyType);

            $arrReplyType = array();


            while ($qandaqrystmt->fetch()) {

            $arrReplyType[ $qandaQuestionId ] = $qandaReplyType;
          }

            $qandaqrystmt->close();


        function ExpandOptionType($option) { 

        ...

             foreach($options as $indivOption) {

                 if($qandaReplyType == 'Single'){

        ...

                 }
                 else if ($qandaReplyType == 'Multiple'){

        ...
             }
          }

        }
```

ATTEMPT:

```
var $reply;
function ExpandOptionType($qandaReplyType) { 
    $this->reply = $qandaReplyType; 


         if($qandaReplyType == 'Single'){
...     

}
 }else if($qandaReplyType == 'Multiple'){
...     }
}
}
```

Comment: What about using `$this->variable` ?

Comment: @mario That is what i have attempted before but I just do not know how it is written, if I can see a code snippet in how it is written for above example, then I will be able to use the code snippet to see how this is implemented and I can use this as an example for future use

Comment: http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/php-objects-page-1.php

Comment: @mario I am recieving an undefined T_VAR when following the example in my attempt which I posted below my question. What should this be and do you see any other issues with the attempt?

Comment: Just use the prefix for **all** variables *that need to be transferred from one to the other method*. Not for entirely local variables like $reply. I have no idea what you are doing, and you're not showing the complete code, or notice/error messages. Yes, when unversed, use it in *all* methods.

Comment: @mario I have no idea what I am doing, that is why I asked for a code snippet so I can see what I need to do and refer to it for future use. This would have saved us a lot of time, save us a lot of hassle and save me from getting a down vote. Even now I do not understand what you said in your comment, and I did not post rest of code because rest of code is irrelevant. Please can you just show me a code snippet on what it should look like so I can physically see how it is done. I just want to use a mysqli variable in an if statement within a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you use `$this` to transfer variables from one method to the other.

```
class database {

     function do_query($id) {

          $result = db("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=?", $id);

          $this->shared_result[] = $result["column"];
        # ^^^^^^^
     }


     function expand_evil($options) {

         foreach ($options as $whatever) {

             if ("Unicorn" == $this->shared_result) {
                            # ^^^^^^^
                ...
             }

         }
     }
}
```

Comments will not be answered. Tutorials do exist.

Answer (score 2):

It's a really long time time since i used last time mysqli but i try to help you.
From your posted code is really difficult to understand if you are in a script, in a class or on more than one class..

In case you are in a class don't forget to use $this.
bind means that you pass the variable pointer/reference, call it as you prefer, not the value so where you exit from the loop the pointer is set to a null position. Specially after the close statement.

You should use the variable binding only if you want to pass the result to a function or more genefally to a code block which would compute a new value (doesn't matter if you return the new value or not) starting from the recived one.
In this case I truly invite you to process directly the binded results otherwise you should pass them by value not by reference.

Hope this help.

Marco

Comment: Hi, as I stated to mario, if you can show me a code snippet in how to implement it for the above example, I will be able to see how it is writen and I can use it as reference for future functions I am creating with mysqli variables inside

Comment: Laterali i'll write you a short example but why you are notte using pdo? Pdo canzone simplify you code